# Modify the object’s properties with help of the spread operator cause the original object modified?

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

Sorry for the noob question, but how the object in the original array got modified? I extracted the small snippset.

- Expected: the `mappedEvents.u` got extra property, while the origin `update` not
- Happened: both `mappedEvents.u` and `update.u` have the same value.

```js
 const update= [
        {
            "_id": "2QK5mmqERN8dd6LaL",
            "open": true,
            "alert": false,
            "unread": 0,
            "userMentions": 0,
            "groupMentions": 0,
            "ts": "2019-09-20T03:20:50.927Z",
            "rid": "GENERAL",
            "name": "general",
            "t": "c",
            "u": {
                "_id": "5JzjbnZDcxKMYR2mv",
                "username": "honga",
                
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2020-01-02T06:34:53.747Z",
            "ls": "2020-01-02T06:34:53.681Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "ox3hxbxdKpenLmyKT",
            "rid": "5JzjbnZDcxKMYR2mvyBShq8ZDfx9isv2sA",
            "u": {
                "_id": "5JzjbnZDcxKMYR2mv",
                "username": "honga",
                
            },
            "_updatedAt": "2020-01-16T10:32:43.414Z",
            "alert": false,
            "fname": "lolo",
            "groupMentions": 0,
            "ls": "2020-01-16T10:32:43.414Z",
            "name": "lol",
            "open": true,
            "t": "d",
            "ts": "2020-01-16T09:26:13.665Z",
            "unread": 0,
            "userMentions": 0
        }
    ];

const mappedEvents = update.map(e => {
  e.u = {...e.u,"avatarOrigin": "upload"};
  return e;
});
console.log({update});
console.log({mappedEvents});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is still accessing the original element's reference where you modify `e.u` property. This has been reflected on the original array. If you want create only new elements with `.map()` then you need to clone the current element as well what you get as a parameter from `.map()`.

Try the following:

```js
const update = [{"_id": "2QK5mmqERN8dd6LaL","u": {"_id": "5JzjbnZDcxKMYR2mv","username": "honga"}},{"_id": "ox3hxbxdKpenLmyKT","u": {"_id": "5JzjbnZDcxKMYR2mv","username": "honga",}}];

const mappedEvents = update.map(e => {
  const newElem = {...e};
  newElem.u = {...e.u,"avatarOrigin": "upload"};
  return newElem;
});
console.log({update});
console.log({mappedEvents});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank for the heads up!